# Could water temperature fluctuations be caused by new plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, shower

I'm having a new bathroom installed. I hired a plumber to do all the water works. He ran all the lines; he is now waiting on sink and toilet to arrive to finish installation. Since he ran new line, we have noticed that the temperature of the water in our current shower fluctuates randomly. We've noticed the same with the water in the kitchen sink.

Is this a symptom of the new plumbing? Can we expect it to clear up after the new plumbing is completed?

Comment: Does it still flucutate after a couple minutes of running?

Comment: yes, i've even noticed it after 10 min.

Comment: can you provide any more details? For instance, if you turn on the cold in the kitchen, does it turn warm? If you turn on hot, does it turn cold?

Comment: I haven't noticed any temperature change when using the cold water. When I use hot water only, I notice temperature changes.

Comment: Did you find out what it was?

Comment: @UNECS: not really, but 1 and 2 on the accepted answer look right for my situation. I guess we'll find out this week when the plumber finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Most common cause of this when there are renovations is cross connection of the hot and cold lines, this can be caused by

1. The shower/bath (or other similar fixtures with a breaching piece) are capped with wall caps (or spindles that don't have a washer in them) and the water can circulate between the hot and cold pipes.
2. The "stubs" under the sink are connected via a pipe externally till the plumber comes back.
3. The Plumber has cross connected the pipes in the wall (Damn!)